# Multi-select picklist issue

Tags: picklist, multi-select

I would like to build a row-level formula with a multipicklist in a report. But I can't even find/select the multi-select picklist field. When I copy the Api Name of the multi-select picklist field into the row-level formula I get the message "This field does not exist". Neither helps the Formula Output Type "text".
**What is the reason that I cannot find/select the field? I have already checked if it is due to the settings of the picklist itself, but couldn't find anything.**

Thanks in advance!
Best,
Kathy

Comment: Is the multi-picklist a field of a standard object or a custom object? In the latter case you need to update the custom report type.

Comment: The multi-picklist field is of a standard object. But we have the same issue with multi-picklist of a custom objectes as well. We have already used the row-level-formulas many times. So that's not the problem. Best regards, Katharina

Comment: Was it supported previously and then changed. There's a knowledge article that suggests creating a Row Level Formula to parse a multi-select picklist value. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326275&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like multi-select picklist is not supported yet in row-level formulae.

The Release Notes state that 'Picklist' is supported, but doesn't mention multi-select picklist:
https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_rd_reports_row_level_formulas.htm

There's an Idea to add multi-select picklist support to row-level formulae here:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003f6kQAA